# How to compare build hashes in react js on production to clear the cache if the versions are different?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have such a task: When changing the build version, delete the cache. I work with already configured webpack and the solution to this problem option I saw hash comparisons, I already have it sewn that during the build a unique hash is set.

```
output: {
    path: paths.appBuild,
    filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js'
 
  },
```

The problem is that I do not know how to compare the version of the current hash and the old one. At the moment, when I build, the following files are generated:

[image: img1]

https://github.com/YevhenSoldatov1998/hash-react/tree/master/build
there is a precache-manifest file, as I understand it, it will be used to compare versions. Even in the main index.js file (in dev) I import serviceWorker.js whose code I took with create-react-app
But when deploying to the console, it displays:

[image: img2]

Here are the webpack configuration files https://github.com/YevhenSoldatov1998/hash-react/tree/master/config

Answer (score 0):

```
const path = require('path');
const cwd = path.resolve(__dirname);
```

```
output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
`
```